# Uncaught Error in snapshot listener. Firebase quota exceeded

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a React Native app which makes use of Firebase Cloud Firestore database. I have implemented multiple snapshot listeners to fetch the different collections. However, I've encountered the following error `[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.]`

I've checked my code and gone back to the developer docs but I'm not able to find where the problem is. I suspect the problem could be with the `getCompetitionCollectionListener` function.

How do I find the exact cause of the error in my code and how would you implement a fix? Did I perhaps write the async call function incorrectly or miss a line of code somewhere?

Database Functions:

```js
import { auth, db } from "../config/firebase.config";
import {
  doc,
  setDoc,
  Timestamp,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

//Create a New User Function.
export const createUserOnRegister = (user, username) => {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
  const userData = {
    email: user.email,
    username: username,
    role: "cosplayer",
    dateCreated: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
  };
  return setDoc(userRef, userData);
};

// Get All Users Function.
export const getAllUsers = async () => {
  const users = [];
  // Query the firestore db for the collection of users
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
  // Loop through the users collection and retrieve the uid of each user
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    let user = { ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id };
    users.push(user);
  });
  return users;
};

//Create a new competition item in the firestore db.
export const newCompetition = (competition) => {
  return addDoc(collection(db, "competitions"), competition);
};

// Return the collection of competitions from the firestore db.
export const getCompetitionCollectionListener = () => {
  return collection(db, "competitions");
};

// Return the collection of entries.
export const getEntryOfCompetition = async (id) => {
  let entries = [];

  const collectionRef = collection(db, "competitions/" + id + "/entries");
  const collectionSnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

  collectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    entries.push(doc.data());
  });
  return entries;
};

// Add a new Entry to the Competition collection.
export const addEntryToCompetition = async (data, id) => {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "competitions/" + id + "/entries");
  // const collectionSnapshot = await addDoc(collectionRef, data);
  return addDoc(collectionRef, data);
};
```

Error Message:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.]
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\construct.js:null in _construct
at node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\wrapNativeSuper.js:null in Wrapper
at http://192.168.1.3:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules\@firebase\util\dist\index.esm2017.js:null in FirebaseError#constructor
at http://192.168.1.3:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:null in j#constructor
at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.rn.js:null in Gs
at node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:null in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _allocateCallback$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:null in callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callReactNativeMicrotasks
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in flushedQueue
```

Rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 12, 12);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage Screenshot:
[Screenshot of Firestore Usage Quota Exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUZ8D.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this error is thrown when you exceeded your quota limit.

Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

Add try catch to your functions so you can know which one is throwing this error and act accordingly

Comment: So why are you asking for help if you know what the problem is ? Add try catch to your functions so you can know which one is throwing this error

Comment: @Dylan i was about to post an answer just like this one, so we seem to be having trouble understanding what you're asking. Consider editing your question to make it clearer. If you're asking where to put try/catches, the spots where you are interacting with firestore are `getDocs`, `setDoc`, and `addDoc`. For a quota error, it's quite possible *all* of these would fail.

Comment: @NicholasTower I will try your suggestion.